# How to get TimeFrame (current or future) for a VSTS iteration

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm using the VSTS REST API to get the iterations of a certain project. What I'm trying to figure out is the "Current iteration".

```
 var vstsConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(VstsUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, VstsPAT));
            var witClient = vstsConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
//get current iteration in VS
            var iterations = witClient.GetClassificationNodeAsync(project: VstsProject, structureGroup: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.TreeStructureGroup.Iterations, depth: 5).Result;


 // i could iterate over the iterations but i'll just get the first one for now..      
            var attributes = iterations.Children.FirstOrDefault().Attributes;
```

Here the attributes give me only the startdate and finishdate. What I'm interested is in the "timeframe" to tell me if it's current or future.

Through calling the `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{teamid}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations`

I do get the 3 fields:

```
{"count":3,"value":[{"id":"f2ac8484-de34-4d5c-8838-cd388a952257","name":"Iteration 1","path":"Web And Mobile Team - Project Documentation\\Iteration 1","attributes":{"startDate":"2018-12-24T00:00:00Z","finishDate":"2018-12-31T00:00:00Z","timeFrame":"current"},"url":"https://url/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/f2ac8484-de34-4d5c-8838-cd388a952257"},{"id":"f57903a8-22e5-474a-a450-a7401a53511e","name":"Iteration 2","path":"Web And Mobile Team - Project Documentation\\Iteration 2","attributes":{"startDate":null,"finishDate":null,"**timeFrame**":"future"},"url":"url/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/f57903a8-22e5-474a-a450-a7401a53511e"},{"id":"2cfc4be3-0665-46de-81e0-0302138bd276","name":"Iteration 3","path":"Web And Mobile Team - Project Documentation\\Iteration 3","attributes":{"startDate":null,"finishDate":null,"**timeFrame**":"future"},"url":"url/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/2cfc4be3-0665-46de-81e0-0302138bd276"}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this examples:

```
string projectName = ""; // your project
string teamName = null; //change it for nondefault team 

var WorkClient = Connection.GetClient<WorkHttpClient>();
TeamContext tcx = new TeamContext(projectName, teamName);

TeamSetting tmsettings = WorkClient.GetTeamSettingsAsync(tcx).Result; // current iteration without dates

Console.WriteLine("Current Iteration: {0} - {1}", tmsettings.DefaultIteration.Name, tmsettings.DefaultIteration.Path);

List<TeamSettingsIteration> iterations = WorkClient.GetTeamIterationsAsync(tcx).Result;  // full information for iterations

foreach (TeamSettingsIteration iteration in iterations)
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} : {2}-{3}", iteration.Attributes.TimeFrame, iteration.Name, iteration.Attributes.StartDate, iteration.Attributes.FinishDate);

TeamSettingsIteration currentiteration = (WorkClient.GetTeamIterationsAsync(tcx, "Current").Result).FirstOrDefault(); // get only current

if (currentiteration != null) Console.WriteLine("Current iteration - {0} : {1}-{2}", currentiteration.Name, currentiteration.Attributes.StartDate, currentiteration.Attributes.FinishDate);
```

Comment: thank you but this is for the Team TFS. I am using Azure DevOps Visual Studio online which is slightly different. Example: I don't have GetTeamIterationsAsync  method for workClient..

Comment: No, I have tested this on Azure DevOps Services. Check your "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" nuget package. I use the last version:  15.131.1

Comment: Here is my project [10.TFRestApiAppManageTeamSettings](https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/tree/master/10.TFRestApiAppManageTeamSettings)

Answer (score 0):

In the REST Api you can add the attribute `$timeframe=current` and you will get the current iteration:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{teamid}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?$timeframe=current&api-version=4.0
```

Comment: thank you, i'm aware of that, callng the api gives you back the timeframe, however, with the client.GetClassificationNodeAsync, I don't see the timeframe..where can I enable it?

Comment: Because WorkItemClassificationNode does not contain the timeframe attribute. You may get it from team settings with WorkHttpClient. You may see that in Shayki example url. So your iteration must be included to some team (like default) then you may identify iteration. Workaround: just compare iteration dates with Datetime.Now )))